# Using native connection while still connected to a vpn

Tags: networking, server, apache2, vpn

I'm setting up a vpn server on a remote development server. The development server has websites that I'm developing and the vpn is in place so that I can tell apache to only accept local connections to view the development sites (instead of opening them to internet and using access control).

However, not having set up a vpn server before, I have a question regarding the client's connection. Let's say I'm connected to the vpn. How can I make it so that only traffic going to certain addresses are sent through the vpn, and all other requests go through my native connection?

It's a little hard to explain so feel free to ask me for more info.

Comment: I believe you're talking about split-tunneling.  Depending on the application/VPN in question, this could be an option in the server configuration.

Comment: @belacqua: I'm using OpenVPN and followed the following tutorial to the letter: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openvpn.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're talking about split-tunneling. Depending on the application/VPN in question, this could be an option in the server configuration.

With OpenVPN, I'm not sure if this is the default.  If you aren't sure what routing is being pushed to the client, it would be easiest just to run a `route` command on the client to see where it think the default is.  You'll really only want the vpn gateway set as a route for the development server(s).  Everything else should default to whatever the normal gateway for the client is.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track with the keywork `split-tunneling`. However, my client is a mac and my networking skills are somewhat lacking -- so your answer is a little obscure to me.

Comment: @MaxMackie You might try to open a terminal on the Mac and try `netstat -nr` instead.

Comment: Right, that worked and I got my routing table. I also found this guide http://dltj.org/article/openvpn-split-routing/. It shows how he set up split-tunnelling.