# How to whitelist / blacklist certain urls not to use VPN connection?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, 19.10, openvpn

Sidenote: I turns out that our OpenVPN server is indeed setup for split tunneling, but our clients are pushing their own gateways:

```
redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp bypass-dns
```

This was done as a workaround to access some internal services that are otherwise unreachable from the outside world. A more proper question would be: What is a proper way to access vpn-internal services without pushing a gateway that would route the entire traffic through the VPN, though I think this is rather [a different question on its own](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222809/what-is-an-alternative-for-pushing-a-gateway-to-access-vpn-internal-resources-wh?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

I'm in homeoffice and while I have set up a stable VPN connection through the Network Manager, its speed is very limited. I have a 1 GBit connection at home, while the VPN connection at the moment only offers 10 MBit.

While certain services have to go through VPN connection, most of the traffic could bypass it just fine as all the VPN would do is to only slow things down. (I'm looking esp. at public data-intensive services like downloading images from the official docker hub or npm registry. Yet just for the sake of setting it up, let's take a service like fast.com.)

How can I whitelist certain websites to make use of the VPN connection or blacklist other sites not to use the VPN connection?

Comment: This might be related or a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/252560/using-native-connection-while-still-connected-to-a-vpn

Comment: What VPN client / Server software solution is being used?

Comment: @tomodachi openvpn

Comment: can you paste output of the command:  ip route

Answer (score 2):

Discuss it with the people who set up VPN for you.

This is commonly known as split routing, where the VPN tunnel will be used for resources that is inside the corporate network, whilst default gateway will be used for the rest. This is usually easier than filtering by service. Commonly, the corporation will have *some* kind of internal plan over the network that makes it easy to provide split routing.

You should check if it's permitted in your organization. Not all organizations allows split routing, because they for instance want to do data loss prevention on your traffic.

Comment: aka "split tunneling" if they wouldn't recognize "split routing"...  **+1**

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives one can try out:

---

- Omit changing default Gateway:

changing "redirect-gateway" option to redirect-private
in your config directive

---

- Only route traffic for VPN through VPN:
  (works if server pushes explicit routes to client)

Check the box under VPN settings -> IPV4 ->
 **"Use this connection only for resources on its network"**
  If they push explicit routes, only that traffic will go through the VPN.

---

- Push non-VPN traffic **outside** of tunnel:

Connect to your VPN then in terminal:

```
host www.sl.se # host you want outside tunnel
194.68.78.65 # the ip of the host above
sudo ip route add 194.68.78.65 dev eth0 # route traffic outside VPN
```

this will route traffic to www.sl.se outside the VPN

---

- Push VPN traffic **Inside** tunnel host-by-host

Connect to your VPN then in terminal:

```
host your-vpn-onlyhost.com # host you want inside of tunnel
 1.1.1.1.1 # the ip of the host above
sudo ip route add 1.1.1.1 dev tun0 # route traffic inside VPN
```

*All examples assume the VPN interface name is tun0
and your network card name is eth0.
And that DNS names are resovable on the Internet.*

Comment: How would I push non-VPN traffic outside if both my wifi and vpn are using the same device, in my case wlp2s0? Can the vpn be set up on another device somehow? (Just followed company instructions for the setup).

Comment: To be clear, I have a l2tp ipsec vpn set up using NetworkManager.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called Split Tunneling.

What you can do depends on the type of user you are in your client machine.
If you are not a sudoer, then this would have to be fixed by one such user, typically a sysadmin.

If you are a sudoer (and assuming it is ok with your organization that you make changes like this; this is up to you to find out), you can follow [this guide](https://forum.htpcguides.com/Thread-Split-Tunnel-Guide-for-Ubuntu-18-04).

Notes:

1. Some changes took place between 16.04 and 18.04, so older guides may not be complete.
2. I do not know if there was any change between 18.04 and 19.10 that makes the guide not to work.

Related:

[Use OpenVPN only for one application/service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146463/use-openvpn-only-for-one-application-service)

https://serverfault.com/questions/792118/openvpn-how-to-stop-public-traffic-routing-through-vpn-server

https://dltj.org/article/openvpn-split-routing/ (from 2010)