# Route traffic outside L2TP IPSEC VPN on Ubuntu 18.04 client

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

When connecting to websites like Netflix and Stadia I would like to route the traffic outside the VPN I have setup to connect to my office. It is a L2TP IPSEC VPN setup through NetworkManager on Ubuntu 18.04.5. I have searched for an answer but none of the solutions I have tried has worked for me.

There are a lot of similar questions to mine on here, but not one of them seem to have a working solution for me. I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223235/734043) very promising. But pushing non-VPN traffic outside of the tunnel did not work for me, so I left a comment.

My main issue is that I have zero networking knowledge. A such I could be making a very simple mistake and not knowing it. Some step by step instructions on how I would route the traffic to certain websites outside my l2tp ipsec vpn would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more info to help me with this, please let me know.

**Edit:** I just realised, maybe this has more to do with the sites I am trying to route outside rather than my setup? Maybe pointing to the stadia.google.com host isn't enough?